# Get pandas dataframe with user input string of dataframe name for a function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, user-input

i have several Pandas dataframes with  names e.g.-timeslices1_df. i want to extract certain columns from this dataframe but with user Input conditions.

```py
def user_input_dataframe():
    
    timeslices_number=int(input("timeslice_number:"))
    process_number=int(input("process_number:"))
    core_number=input("core_number:")
    #timeslices_4__profilerdataprocess_45__c0_us_ example column_name
    dataframe_name="timeslices_"+str(timeslices_number)+"_df"
    column_name="timeslices_"+str(timeslices_number) +'__'+ "profilerdataprocess_"+str(process_number)+'__'+str(core_number)+'_'+"us"
    #print(column_name)
    list_of_datasets = [timeslices0_df,timeslices1_df,timeslices2_df ,timeslices3_df,timeslices4_df,timeslices5_df,
                       timeslices6_df,timeslices7_df,timeslices8_df]
    for index, dataset in enumerate(list_of_datasets):
        if  dataframe_name in dataset:
            X_df=pd.DataFrame()
            X_df.append(dataframe_name)
            X1 = [col for col in X_df.columns if column_name in col]
            X2=pd.DataFrame()
            X2=X_df[X1]
            X2['date'] = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2020', periods=len(X1), freq='D')
            X2=X2.set_index('date')
            return X2
```

I cannot do it as the user Input is a string. I get this error.
Is there any other way of retrieving the dataframe using user Input function?

```
Sample Input: 
   timeslice_number:4

   process_number:45
 
   core_number:c0
Expected Output:new dataframe with a single selected column

Actual Output: Empty dataframe
```

Comment: Please update your post with a sample input and expected output.

Comment: @BalajiAmbresh i have added it

Comment: In what variable is the list of all the dataframes stored?

Comment: @BalajiAmbresh i did not store it as a list before. but i did and added that too

Comment: Please update your post with the details.

Comment: Updated completely

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217318/discussion-between-balaji-ambresh-and-shankar-ram).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you give this a shot?

```py
def user_input_dataframe():
    timeslices_number=int(input("timeslice_number:"))
    process_number=int(input("process_number:"))
    core_number=input("core_number:")
    #timeslices_4__profilerdataprocess_45__c0_us_ example column_name
    column_name="timeslices_"+str(timeslices_number) +'__'+ "profilerdataprocess_"+str(process_number)+'__'+str(core_number)+'_'+"us"
    list_of_datasets = [timeslices0_df,timeslices1_df,timeslices2_df ,timeslices3_df,timeslices4_df,timeslices5_df,
                       timeslices6_df,timeslices7_df,timeslices8_df]
    if timeslices_number >= len(list_of_datasets):
        return None
    dataset = list_of_datasets[timeslices_number]
    X1 = dataset[[col for col in dataset.columns if column_name in col]]
    X1['date'] = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2020', periods=len(X1), freq='D')
    X1=X1.set_index('date')
    return X1
```

Comment: This works. it seems like my loop was not correct. Thank you for the answer

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you want to access variables programmatically. The built in functions [locals()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals) and [globals()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals) let you do that.

```
variable1 = 1
variable2 = 2
variable3 = 3

i = 2
print(locals().get(f'variable{i}'))
# prints '2'

def get_variable(i):
    return globals().get(f'variable{i}')

print(get_variable(3))
# prints '3'
```

But, wouldn't it be cleaner to keep your DataFrames in a list or dict? Something like:

```
timeslice_dfs = [
    timeslices1_df,
    timeslices2_df,
    # etc.
]

dfs = {
    'timeslice1': timeslices1_df,
    # etc.
}
```